# Search for source code for Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache

Tags: .net

I'm looking for the source code for

Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache.

The nuget package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/) lists this https://github.com/dotnet/extensions as the source, however I can't find MemoryCache in there. I found this, but it is in an archived repo. https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCache.cs

What am I missing? Is the current source available?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like release branches are not merged to the master branch. I have found source code of class MemoryCache.cs under https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/3.1/src/Caching/Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs

Comment: Thank you very much :-)